Nothing happened in my table according to "fn_dblog", is that correct?
Yesterday, something happened at a customer site, and I would like to know if my analysis is correct:
In order to know, what happened, I launched the following query:
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%VEHICLES%' AND 
      UPPER(Column_NAME) LIKE '%ACTIVE%'

SELECT * 
FROM fn_dblog(null,null) 
WHERE UPPER(AllocUnitName) LIKE '%VEHICLES%'

The result of the first query is:
TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME
Vehicles      Active

=> This is indeed the column in the exact table of which I'd like to know if the value has been changed.
The result of the second query is empty.
This might mean that that particular table's contents have not changed at all.
I doubt about this, because I'm not working on the database itself, but on a restored backup that I've just copied from the customer.
I have taken a backup because the customer's system is that weak that the mentioned query (especially the second one) does not yield any result, even after a long time of processing.
This might mean two things:

Either my way of working is right: the contents of that table have indeed not been modified.
Either my way of working is wrong: the backup I've taken does not even contain the data I'm looking for, so my analysis is worthless.

Can somebody tell me which thing is right and in case the mentioned backup does not contain the required data, then how should I configure the backup in order to contain it?
Thanks in advance
According to the first answer, which starts with the "desesperating" title "2little2late", the information I'm looking for would be present in the transaction log. I'll attach the different tabs of the backup feature. Is there any option I might use for having the transaction log in my backup?

Hereby the database properties of the original database. As you can see, the recovery model is "Full" ("Complet" is French for "Full"):


2little2late
The function you're using (fn_dblog) will only show active log records in your transaction log. That means if you're in full or bulk logged, and someone has taken a transaction log backup, they've been cleared out. That also means if you're in simple recovery and a checkpoint has been triggered, they're gone.
If your database is in full or bulk logged recovery, and you have access to the transaction log backups taken around the time you’re interested in examining, you can use fn_dump_dblog instead. You’ll need to ask your client if those exist.
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    fn_dump_dblog 
(
    NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, N'A:\Path\To\Your\TransactionLog.bak',
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT
) AS d;

Since neither of these functions is well documented aside from scattered blog posts, you should be careful where you run them.
